# Более удобный синтаксис для динамического ключа

Tags: php

Приложение для взаимодействия с SOAP и при разборе полученных данных столкнулся вот с таким некрасивым синтаксисом:

```
$method = 'FindCompanyByCode';
$getResult = $method.'Result';

if($result->$getResult == 'Data not found') {
 // some code
}
```

Составной ключ приходится заранее объявлять в переменной, можно ли как-то сократить и избежать использования переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует так называемый **сложный синтаксис**:

```
if ($result->{$method . 'Result'}) {
```